# Unable to find a target named Runner in project Runner.xcodeproj, did find '<MyProjectName>' (Flutter Project)

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods

Steps to Reproduce:

```
% cd iOS

ios % arch -x86_64 pod install
```

(`flutter run` fails with the same error)

Results:

```
[!] Unable to find a target named Runner in project Runner.xcodeproj, did find MyProjectName.
```

Doctor:

```
% flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.2, on macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-arm, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.3.2 on channel stable at /Users/tenna/デベロッパー/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision e3c29ec00c (6 weeks ago), 2022-09-14 08:46:55 -0500
    • Engine revision a4ff2c53d8
    • Dart version 2.18.1
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tenna/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A400
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.50.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • SCG08 (mobile)     • RFCR71VND0N               • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • tenna (2) (mobile) • 00008030-0012304A01D3402E • ios            • iOS 16.0 20A362
    • macOS (desktop)    • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 106.0.5249.119
    ! Error: Failed to prepare the device for development. This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the
      installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your Mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility. (code 806)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Both flutter run and pod install was working fine till yesterday.
Suddenly started happening today with every flutter project I have.

Also, when I try to run with android, it fails with a bunch of "Couldn't find constructor" errors.

Tried with changing target name to "Runner" from "", then it caused this error:

```
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: check your ios folder if you have a runner directory. that is what your error is saying

Comment: Yes I do have a runner directory. It is basic flutter project.

Comment: if there is, then what i can propose is to delete `runner folder`, `Pods folder`, `Podfile.lock`, `Runner.xcodeproj`, `Runner.xcworkspace.`  delete all of these and go to your root folder and run `flutter create .` then flutter run

Answer (score 0):

Changed back the target name to 'Runner', and pod install from terminal, then, run with Xcode solved the problem.
Don't know why this happened because Target name has been changed a long time ago, and was working fine..